# Intersection of plane and sphere

Tags: geometry, 3d, spheres

Suppose I have a plane $$z=x+3$$ and sphere $$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 6z$$ what will be their intersection ?

I wrote the equation for sphere as 
$$x^2 + y^2 + (z-3)^2 = 9$$ with center as (0,0,3) which satisfies the plane equation, meaning plane will pass through great circle and their intersection will be a circle.

However when I try to solve equation of plane and sphere I get

$$x^2 + y^2 + (x+3)^2 = 6(x+3)$$

which does not looks like a circle to me at all. What did I do wrong?

Comment: It is a circle in 3D. When you substitute $z$, you implicitly project your circle on the plane $z=0$, so you see an ellipsis

Comment: Special cases like this are somewhat a waste of effort, compared to tackling the problem in its most general formulation.  The beauty of solving the general problem (intersection of sphere and plane) is that you can then apply the solution in any problem context.  If, on the other hand, your expertise was squandered on a special case, you cannot be sure that the result is reusable in a new problem context.

Comment: @Exodd Can you explain what you mean? While you explain it can you also tell me what I should substitute if I want to project the circle on z=1 (say) instead?

Comment: @suraj the projection is exactly the same, since $z=0$ and $z=1$ are parallel planes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Center of circle: at $(0,0,3)$ , radius = $3$.

Plane $z = x +3$  passes through center.

Normal of plane: $(1,0,-1)$ .

Let vector $(a,b,c)$ be perpendicular to this normal:

$(a,b,c) \cdot (1,0,-1)$ = $0$  ; $a - c = 0$.

Yields  2  independent, orthogonal vectors perpendicular to the normal $(1,0,-1)$ of the plane:

1) $(1/√2)(1,0,1)$ and

2) $(0,1,0)$.

Let $\vec{s}$ = $\alpha (1/√2)(1,0,1) +\beta (0,1,0)$.

In analogy to a circle traced in the $x, y$ - plane:

$\vec{s} \cdot (1/√2)(1,0,1)$ = $3 cos(\theta)$ = $\alpha$.

$\vec{s} \cdot (0,1,0)$ = $3 sin(\theta)$ = $\beta$

Finally the parameter representation of the great circle:

$\vec{r}$ = $(0,0,3) + (1/√2)3cos(\theta)(1,0,1) + 3sin(\theta)(0,1,0)$

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, if I'm not mistaken, is that something similar to doing a base change?

Answer (score 2):

The plane has equation $x-z+3=0$
the center is in the plane so the intersection is the great circle of equation

$$x^2+y^2+x^2=9$$or

$$(x\sqrt {2})^2+y^2=9$$
which is an ellipse. to get the circle, you must add the second equation 
$$z=x+3$$

Comment: In case you were just given the last equation how can you find center and radius of such a circle in 3d?

Comment: the center is $(0,0,3) $ and the radius is $3$.

Comment: I think this answer would be better if it included a more complete explanation, but I have checked it and found it to be correct.

Comment: To complete Salahamam's answer: the center of the sphere is at $(0,0,3)$, which also lies on the plane, so the intersection ia a great circle of the sphere and thus has radius $3$.